# Swift working with API "to fast"?

Tags: json, rest, web, swift, request

I m currently working with the League of Legends API for a small App - it require me to send some requests after each other but currently i m running into a problem.
Here is my Code first of all

```
import UIKit

var summonorname:String = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var SummonorID = ""


    @IBOutlet weak var Input: UITextField!
    @IBAction func SubmitBT(sender: AnyObject) {
        summonorname = Input.text
        println(summonorname)

        let urlpath_summonorID = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+summonorname+"?api_key=12345-12345-12345-12345-12345"


        let url_summonorID = NSURL(string: urlpath_summonorID)
        let session_1 = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task_1 = session_1.dataTaskWithURL(url_summonorID, completionHandler: {data,response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
            }else{
                let summonorID_JSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
                var ID_dict = summonorID_JSON["testsummonor"] as NSDictionary
                var SummonorID: AnyObject? = ID_dict["id"]
                println(SummonorID!)
            }
        })

        task_1.resume()

        let urlpath_summonorLeague = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/"+self.SummonorID+"?api_key= 12345-12345-12345-12345-12345"
        println(urlpath_summonorLeague)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The first request get sended fine and i get the JSON and can parse it, but

```
let urlpath_summonorLeague = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/"+self.SummonorID+"?api_key=12345-12345-12345-12345-12345"
        println(urlpath_summonorLeague)
```

This part is sended to fast so it still missing "self.SummonorID" and the "self.SummonorID" is printed after like:

```
OUTPUT
testsummonor
https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/?api_key=12345-12345-12345-12345-12345
00000001
```

anyway to fix this with like "let the request return first" and then go to the next step?

Answer (score 0):

You are only initiating one task in your code. If you want something to be done after the *completion* task put it, well, into the *completion handler*.

Comment: see post below, but this didn't even work (it gives me the same output)

Answer (score 0):

@Mundi

```
import UIKit

var summonorname:String = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var SummonorID = ""


    @IBOutlet weak var Input: UITextField!
    @IBAction func SubmitBT(sender: AnyObject) {
        summonorname = Input.text
        println(summonorname)

        let urlpath_summonorID = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+summonorname+"?api_key=12345-12345-12345-12345-12345"


        let url_summonorID = NSURL(string: urlpath_summonorID)
        let session_1 = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task_1 = session_1.dataTaskWithURL(url_summonorID, completionHandler: {data,response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
            }else{
                let summonorID_JSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
                var ID_dict = summonorID_JSON["testsummonor"] as NSDictionary
                var SummonorID: AnyObject? = ID_dict["id"]
                println(SummonorID!)
let urlpath_summonorLeague = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/"+self.SummonorID+"?api_key= 12345-12345-12345-12345-12345"
        println(urlpath_summonorLeague)

            }
        })

        task_1.resume()


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```